# Emulate form submit behavior using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am submitting formData using ajax and from the server I am getting html as response. Now I want to load this html (this is what would have automatically happened if I would have submitted the form instead of using ajax). I used `$("html").load(response)` but it is not running javascripts I think. Is there a way I can emulate submit form behavior using ajax?

Comment: Why not use a real form submit, if you want to perform the same behaviour?

Comment: I am adding files dynamically into formData so cannot use real form submit

Comment: Have you checked your Network tab to see if your server is actually returning the full HTML document as the response body?

Comment: Yes it is returning the full html. Earlier when I was using real form submit, the returned page was loading without any error. Now the console is throwing `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` error

Comment: I would suggest posting the data, checking the response, and then performing a Redirect to a new page that can contain the new data.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty this is what even I would like to do, but I don't have the url to redirect to I only have new data, is it possible to redirect without url?

Comment: @Satyam that doesn't make sense. Where are you getting `response` from? Otherwise you'd want to look at `.html()`. not `.load()`